# taking value from checkbox

Tags: php, html

i am working on a quiz app in php,i currently uses radio button,but now  a modification is nedded that a user must able to select multiple option as answer,so i used checkbox instead of radio button
    echo"

```
                <input type=radio style=\"vertical-align:middle;margin-top:0\" name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option1}\" >
                $option1
                </br>

                <input type=radio style=\"vertical-align:middle;margin-top:0\" name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option2}\">
                 $option2
                </br>

                <input type=radio style=\"vertical-align:middle;margin-top:0\" name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option3}\">
                $option3
                </br>

                <input type=radio style=\"vertical-align:middle;margin-top:0\" name=\"{$id}\" value=\"{$option4}\">
                 $option4

                </br></br></div>";
```

in above code name variable is assigned the value of question no,so if i use checkbox instead of radio button,how can i take values of multiple answes that user select,is there any other method?thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must add [] to the name of each checkbox

```
        <input type=checkbox style=\"vertical-align:middle;margin-top:0\" name=\"{$id}[]\" value=\"{$option1}\" >
        $option1
        </br>
```

Answer (score 1):

For radio buttons in a group you need to take the same name for all buttons. For check boxes just use different names and then you may address them one by one.

If you take the same name for all check boxes, just use `name=\"{$id}[]\"` which will result in an array in PHP `$_POST[$id]` - but then you don't know which index is which button.